# Переход по SWF баннеру, если в нем не прописана ссылка

Tags: swf, flash, href, html, flv

Рекламодатель прислал для размещения на сайте SWF баннер, в котором не прописан переход на сайт по нажатию на баннере. Пытался ему втолковать, что нужно в исходнике прописать саму ссылку и событие по клику на баннере, но он никак не поймет. Сегодня баннер размещать, а он все никак не вдуплит. Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы щелкая по баннеру переходили на его сайт?

Answer (score 1):

Попробовать подключить js к объекту, а в js прописать, чтобы при клике пользователь переходил на сайт.

Answer (score 1):

поставь баннеру wmode: 'opaque' а поверх него сделай прозрачный блок установив z-index. На блок поставь ссылку.

проще всего установи сразу после баннера

```
<a href="http://site.com" class="link"></a>

<style>
.link {
   display:block;
   position:relative;
   z-index:1;
   width:240px;
   height:400px;
   margin-top:-400px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй этот баннер обернуть в `<div>`. Перед </head> напиши функцию

```
<script>
    function advertising() {
      window.location = "http://mysite.com"
    }
</script>
```

Ну и в этот `<div>` которым обернули вставьте `onclick="advertising()"`

Полный код:

```
<div onclick="advertising()">banner.swf</div>
```

Comment: Объясните более подробно причину. Так как 'Я' понял причину, этого условия достаточно. Под какой CMS Вы работаете ???

Answer (score 0):

Попробовать вложить баннер/swf в другую флешку, и перехватить клик.

Answer (score 0):

Sothink SWF Decompiler (второй раз о нём пишу).

Как правило разработчики баннеров всё таки прописывают параметр для перехода. Но он почти всегда пустой. Пользуюсь этой программой именно для того чтобы узнать как обозвать переменную передаваемую в ролик.

А иначе - как [@AlekseyB](/users/8574/alekseyb) советует.

Comment: А там как?

Answer (score 0):

1. Sothink SWF Decompiler - перекинуть исходный swf в fla
2. открыть fla в Adobe Flash CS5 например
3. собственно сделать требуемый переход стандартно: добавить слой, поместить в него прозрачный прямоугольник перекрыв всю область банера, сделать прямоугольник кнопкой, повесить код (например Action Script 2.0):

```
on (release) {
     getURL("http://www.mysite.ru", _blank);
}
```

4. опубликовать fla обратно в swf, готово